# Adding a container to HTML Email without moving the Content Areas

Tags: html, email

We are trying to get the gray background to extend all the way to the left border and the top of content area "Bottom1".  I was hoping a container would work around all left content areas but it pushed the right content areas down.

We would like the gray to be the background of the area highlighted in red, there is about 10pixels of white to the left and another 10 at the bottom (see image [content areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwedn.jpg))

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
    ReadMsgBody {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .ExternalClass {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .ExternalClass,
    .ExternalClass p,
    .ExternalClass span,
    .ExternalClass font,
    .ExternalClass td,
    .ExternalClass div {
      line-height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
    p {
      margin: 1em 0;
    }
    table td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    img {
      outline: 0;
    }
    a img {
      border: none;
    }
    p {
      margin: 1em 0;
    }
    @-ms-viewport{ width:device-width;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body[yahoo] .container {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] .footer {
      width: auto !important;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    body[yahoo] .content-padding {
      padding: 4px !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] .mobile-hidden {
      display: none !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] .logo {
      display: block !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] img {
      width: auto !important;
      max-width: 308px !important;
      height: auto !important;
      max-height: auto !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] .header img {
      width: auto !important;
      max-width: 316px !important;
      height: auto !important;
      max-height: auto !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] .photo img {
      width: 100% !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] .drop {
      display: block !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      float: left;
      clear: both;
    }
    body[yahoo] .footerlogo {
      display: block !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      padding-top: 15px;
      float: left;
      clear: both;
    }
    body[yahoo] .nav4,
    body[yahoo] .nav5,
    body[yahoo] .nav6 {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    body[yahoo] .container {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] .mobile-hidden {
      display: none !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] .logo {
      display: block !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] .photo img {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
    }
    body[yahoo] .nav5,
    body[yahoo] .nav6 {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
  a:link {
    color: #318ab8
  }
  hr {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000; margin: 0px; padding:0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" yahoo="fix">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
        <custom type="header" name="header">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" class="container" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" bordercolor="#E0E0E0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" class="header" valign="top">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bordercolor="" width="100%" bgcolor="">
                      <tr>
                        <td valign="top" align="center">
                          <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" bordercolor="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size:13px;">
                                <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" align="center">
                                  <img id="image-placeholder" src="http://image.comm.housingpartnership.net/lib/fe9513727667017c70/m/1/Member-Newsletter.jpg" border="0" title="hpn_gradient2" mdid="9ca2b877-03cd-4677-b5ce-01c161cb0446" />
                                </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="left">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #6d6e71" align="left" valign="top" colspan="3" class="drop">
                          <custom type="content" name="Top1">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="content-padding" style="padding-right:10px; padding-left: 10px">
                          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="drop" valign="top" width="38%" align="left">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #e0e0e0" class="container" width="100%">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                      <custom type="content" name="left1" ">
            </td>
           </tr>
              
           <tr>
            <td align="left " valign="top "   style="padding-top: 10px; ">
            <custom type="content " name="left2 ">
            </td>
           </tr>
                          
           <tr>
            <td align="left " valign="top "   style="padding-top: 10px; ">
            <custom type="content " name="left3 ">
            </td>
           </tr>
                          
           <tr>
            <td align="left " valign="top "  style="padding-top: 10px; ">
            <custom type="content " name="left4 ">
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
          </td>
          <td class="drop " valign="top " width="2% " height="10 "><img alt=" " src="http://image.S7.exacttarget.com/lib/ffcf14/m/1/spacer.gif " height="10 " width="10 " style="display: block; "/></td>
          <td class="drop " width="60% " valign="top ">
          <table border="0 " cellpadding="0 " cellspacing="0 " width="100% ">
           <tr>
            <td align="left " valign="top ">
            <custom type="content " name="right1 ">
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td align="left " valign="top " style="padding-top: 10px; ">
            <custom type="content " name="right2 ">
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td align="left " valign="top " style="padding-top: 10px; ">
            <custom type="content " name="right3 ">
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td align="left " valign="top " style="padding-top: 10px; ">
            <custom type="content " name="right4 ">
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="left " valign="top " colspan="3 " class="drop " style="padding-top:10px; ">
          <custom type="content " name="bottom1 ">
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="left " valign="top " colspan="3 " class="drop " style="padding-top:10px; ">
          <custom type="content " name="bottom2 ">
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="left " valign="top " colspan="3 " class="drop " style="padding-top:10px; ">
          <custom type="content " name="bottom3 ">
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="left " valign="top " colspan="3 " class="drop " style="padding-top:10px; ">
          <custom type="content " name="bottom4 ">
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="left " valign="top " colspan="3 " class="drop " style="padding-top:10px; ">
          <custom type="content " name="bottom5 ">
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="left " valign="top " colspan="3 " class="drop " style="padding-top:10px; ">
          <custom type="content " name="bottom6 ">
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#E0E0E0 ">
      <td align="left " valign="top " colspan="3 " class="drop ">
      <table width="100% " border="0 " cellpadding="0 " cellspacing="0 ">
      <hr size="2 " color="#c91f40 " />
        <center><font face="Arial " size="2 "><span style="color: #c61f40; ">Boston: </span>One Washington Mall, Boston, MA 02108&nbsp;</center>
        <center><span style="color: #c61f40; ">Washington, DC:</span> 820 First Street NE, Suite 760, Washington, DC 20002&nbsp;</font></center>
        </br>
        <table width="100% " cellspacing="0 " cellpadding="2 " bgcolor="#e0e0e0 " align="center ">
        <tbody>
          <td align="left " valign="center ">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a conversion="true " alias="HPN - Facebook " title="HPN - Facebook " href="http://www.facebook.com/housingpartnershipnetwork/?fref=ts "><img width="29 " vspace="0 " border="0 " hspace="0
                                      " height="25 " mdid="2d055585-c95d-4d6c-8e6a-cdb9d3109034 " alt="FB-f-Logo-sm " title="FB-f-Logo-sm " src="http://image.comm.housingpartnership.net/lib/fe9513727667017c70/m/1/FB-f-Logo__blue_29.png " style="width: 25px; height:
                                      25px; " /></a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a conversion="true " alias="HPN - Twitter " title="HPN - Twitter " href="http://twitter.com/HPN_Network "><img width="29 " vspace="0 " border="0 " hspace="0 " height="24 " mdid="1e9bba64-4161-4532-983d-181da3210430
                                      " alt="Twitter_logo2 " title="Twitter_logo2 "src="http://image.comm.housingpartnership.net/lib/fe9513727667017c70/m/1/Twitter_logo2.png " style="width: 29px; height: 24px; " /></a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a conversion="true " alias="HPN - LinkedIn " title="HPN - LinkedIn " href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/housing-partnership-network "><img width="28 " vspace="0 " border="0 " hspace="0 " height="25 " mdid="1507e12c-4f2a-4661-9a67-f42d462aca01
                                      " alt="LinkedIn_Logo2 " title="LinkedIn_Logo2 " src="http://image.comm.housingpartnership.net/lib/fe9513727667017c70/m/1/LinkedIn_Logo2.png " style="width: 28px; height: 25px; " /></a>
          </td>
          <td align="right " valign"center "><a conversion="true " alias="HPN Website " title="HPN Website " href="http://www.housingpartnership.net "><img width="133 " vspace="0 " border="0 " hspace="0 " height="40 " style="padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom:
                                      10px; width: 133px; height: 40px; " src="http://image.comm.housingpartnership.net/lib/fe9513727667017c70/m/1/hpn_40px.png " title="hpn_40px_footer " alt="HPN Logo " mdid="954b4bc9-826e-43ad-8035-f4d542d15029 " />
          </td>
        </tbody>
        </table>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td valign="top "><custom type="footer " name="footer "></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<custom name="opencounter " type="tracking ">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please trim down your code to just the required items and post a jsfiddle, codepen, or other demo. A massive code dump isn't going to get you answers.

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry still new here I will just post the section we are looking to add a container too.

Comment: If you could also make a jsfiddle of the code, that would be great